# Making classes private to force class to be injected by IOC container in c#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Is this a good idea?

```
public sealed class ConcreteClass : IConcreteClass
    {
        private ConcreteClass ()
        {

        }

        public void ExecuteSomething()
        {

        }
    }
```

in dependancy resolver:

```
 kernel.Bind<IConcreteClass>().To<ConcreteClass>();
```

If there are some that didn't know this can be done - it can.

This forces anyone who needs to use this code to inject it. It can't be instantiated manually.

Do you see anything wrong with this?

Comment: How would you test it in isolation?

Comment: Test the public class that uses the private constructor class. The class is private and shouldn't be tested

Comment: `sealed` means you can't inherit from it, not that you can't construct it (how would the DI container construct it?) - does that change the premise of your question?

Comment: You have a `ExactTargetClient` constructor in `ConcreteClass` ? That's not a legal c# code. Apart from that I don't understand your question too.

Comment: I know what sealed means. The construcotr is private, that is the point. ninject has a setting to construct private contructor classes. Maybe by means of reflection

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel code ammended

Comment: What value do you gain by doing so? Not a rhetorical question; I am genuinely interested.

Comment: To prevent people using the library from not injecting it. To force injection.

Comment: Ok, makes more sense now.  But still: _"This forces anyone who needs to use this code to inject it. It can't be instantiated manually."_ - If Ninject can construct it this way, so can someone else if they _really_ want to.  Better to just keep those classes internal and expose the interfaces publically - even then if people want to get at the internal classes they can do so through reflection.

Comment: @James Thorpe this is true, but if the contructor is private it makes it obvious that i do not intend this class to be instantiated manually.

Comment: You gain nothing by doing so. People can use reflection to create instance still. Also, educate your colleagues to use injection, don't force them. If you've educated them enough, they will not instantiate it themselves.

Comment: I still don't understand what value this gives you. If I really wanted to create an instance of your class I could do so with reflection, which is just what typical DI containers are doing. What wider value do you perceive this as bringing to your code? Security? Abstraction? Looser coupling?

Comment: Sriram Sakthivel Its about making the intent of the code obvious. We cant always rely on developers to know things

Comment: why do you want to force someone to use injection? what benefit does that have? What if they want to use a different DI framework? Or if they want to do their DI manually?

Comment: The only dissadvantage i can see is if the DI framework can't new up private constructors.

Comment: Perhaps you start talking with other developers in your team, instead of trying to find 'clever' ways of forcing people into certain practices. This will never work, because they will find ways around your tricks.

Comment: No, by making a constructor private, you're not making the intent obvious. It creates confusion. How does a developer know to use IOC container if the constructor is private? I don't find the magic.

Comment: @Steven again, its about making the intent of the code clear not exactly "forcing" people to do things.

Comment: A private constructor to me is a signpost that I should be looking for a static property that returns a singleton instance, not that I should be expecting to have one injected.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments is seems that you want to force injection. The way to do this is to have your classes require their dependencies through their constructor, not to obfuscate intent by making your classes follow strange conventions.

DI is a technique, frameworks make that simpler, but the important thing is to **educate** people as to why they should follow the principle. You can 'force' the changes you want by making your constructors so that they require the dependencies. How they then construct them is up to the client, but if the constructor has the dependency in it then they will have to inject an instance to use the class.

Comment: Hi Sam, "The way to do this is to have your classes require their dependencies through their constructor,". This doesn't force DI. You can just new up instances that implement that interface. It doesnt require the use of a DI framework

Comment: No, this does force DI, but it doesn't force use of a framework. You seem to be confusing the concept of DI with the frameworks that implement it

Comment: and maybe you should clarify why you want to force the use of a framework? And why you don't want people to construct your class...

Comment: The question says "force class to be injected by IOC container in c#".

Comment: @user1809104 It also says "Is this a good idea?" - the answer to which is "no".